# Docker with apache2/php5 cannot connect to mysql on host machine

Tags: mysql, sockets, docker, localhost

I am trying to spin up a container to run a legacy webapp that needs `php5.3`. I want the container to access the `mysql` server on the host (i.e., the computer hosting the docker container). The `mysql` server is confirmed up and running, and I can log into it from the host computer.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

VOLUME ["/var/www"]
VOLUME ["/etc/ssl"]

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      apache2 \
      php5 \
      php5-cli \
      libapache2-mod-php5 \
      php5-gd \
      php5-ldap \
      php5-mysql \
      php5-pgsql

COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./site1 /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1
COPY ./site2 /etc/apache2/sites-available/site2
COPY ./apache2-foreground.sh /var/apache2-foreground.sh

RUN a2ensite site1
RUN a2ensite site2

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["bash", "/var/apache2-foreground.sh"]
```

The `apache2-foreground.sh` script comes from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/php/master/apache2-foreground).

I deploy the container using this command:

```
docker run --detach \
       --name legacy-php5.3 \
       --net="host" \
       -p 80:80 \
       -p 443:443 \
       -v /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl \
       -v /var/www:/var/www \
       my/php5.3
```

The `--net="host"` argument, if I understand correctly, should make the host's `localhost` accessible to the container. However, the container cannot connect to the mysql server on the host. The php command `echo mysql_error()` tells me `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`.

If I "`ssh`" into the container, and run `$ mysql -h localhost -u <my_user> -p`, then it tells me `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`.

On the host computer, the socket file is there:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.*
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 6 Sep  6 12:16 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Sep  6 12:16 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 6 Sep  6 12:16 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which os you  are using? mean your host os?

Comment: `localhost` is the unix socket within the container. To use the socket on the host you'd need `-v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld` to map the socket on host into the container. Alternately use TCP by specifying 127.0.0.1 as the host for you application along with `--net="host"`

Comment: @danblack is it better to declare the VOLUME in the `Dockerfile` or in the `docker run...`?

Comment: You'd probably need both. Being explicit in the `Dockerfile` shows you're explicitly intending this to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @DavidMaze I saw that question, but the answer lacks details about my socket problem. danblack's comment above solved the problem. I wish it were an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: MySQL has some broken behavior around `localhost`: even though it's a valid DNS name, if you request a network connection to `localhost` it will try to make a Unix socket connection instead.  But (as the linked question suggests) you don't want `localhost` here in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is the unix socket within the container and not a tcp connection to the localhost IP address. To access the unix socket on the host you'd need `-v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld` to map the socket on host into the container. You'll also need `VOLUME /var/run/mysqld` in the `Dockerfile`.

Alternately use TCP by specifying 127.0.0.1 as the host for your application along with `--net="host"` in the `docker run` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understand it correctly but before going into detail I will mention important statement about host network.

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not
>   supported on Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, or Docker EE for
>   Windows Server.

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Now in Linux, it's working as you expect.

Run nginx for testing

```
docker run --rm -it --network host --name my_nginx nginx:alpine
```

Goto your container...

```
docker exec -it my_nginx ash
```

If you `cat /etc/hosts`

You will all the host file inside the container is same as the host file of the Host Machine.

Now, run the other test image, just a public image from docker registry.

```
docker run --name="hello-world" -d -p 8080:8080 kornkitti/express-hello-world
```

If you do inside nginx container

```
apk add curl
curl localhost:8080
```

A hello world response from nodejs container.

For mysql It also working...

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -ptest
```

In case of window or Mac you can add the following.

```
docker run --rm -it --add-host=db.local.com:(host__ip_address) --name my_nginx nginx:alpine
```

And connect to mysql from containers like

```
mysql -h db.local.com -u root -ptest
```